# Site works fine on localhost but doesnot respond calculations on hosting server

Tags: performance, localhost

I have created simple conversion form that takes input from user and calculate the result without pressing button. My problem is that it works fine on localhost but when I upload it on free hosting site it doesn't respond with calculations. JQuery also doesn't work when I press the div on the top left of my form it highlights on local but not when I upload Please help.

Here is my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function(e){
        $("input").change(function(){
            var total=0;
            $("input[name=qww]").each (function(){
                total=10*parseInt($(this).val());

            })
            $("input[name=long]").val(total);
           
        });
    });
            
    </script> -->
   
<style type="text/css">
.main{

    height:400px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#compare{
    height: 50px;
    width: 147px;
    background-color: white;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: orange;
    float: left;
   
   

}
#compare2{
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: white ;
    float: right;
    

}
#compare4{
   
    height: 35px;
    width: 147px;
    background-color: white;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: orange;
    float: left;
   
   

}
#compare5{
    
    height: 35px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: white ;
    float: right;
    

}
.form{

height: 150px;
width: 300px;
background-color: white;
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.Myform{
padding: 5px 0;


}
input[type=text]{
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    font-style: oblique;
    font-size: 18px;
   outline: none;
   border: none;
   font-weight:bolder;

}
.qwerty{
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(122, 16, 122);
    color: blue;
}
.button{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -WEbkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #ccc;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}
.text{
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
    -WEbkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #ccc;
}
.initial{
    height: 15px;
    margin-top: 50px;
   
    width: 147px;
    background-color: white;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: orange;
     }
     .image{

         width: 40px;
         height: 15px;
         margin-left: 10px;
     }
     img{
         vertical-align: top;
     }
     .highLight{
    background-color: #333333;
}
.panel{
    -webkit-transition:0.3s;
    transition:0.3s;
    opacity:1;
}
.panel:not(.highLight){
    opacity:0.5;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="initial" style="float: left; font-size: 10px; text-align: center; color: blue;"  >
        COMPARE</div>
        <div class="initial" style="float: right;font-size: 10px; text-align: center; color: blue;">
        VENTA</div>
        <div class="panel" id="compare"style="font-size: 26px;font-weight: bolder; text-align: center;color: black;">3.4000

        </div>
        <div class="panel" id="compare2"style="font-size: 26px;font-weight: bolder; text-align: center;color: black;">3.4306

        </div>
        
        <div class="form">
            
           <div class="text">
            <div class="QWERTY" style="font-size: 10px; text-align: right;color: blue;">
                VENTA</div>
               
               
               <form id="bbb" action="index.html" class="Myform" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">USD
                <label for="" style="font-size: 30px;">&nbsp;$</label> 
                   <input type="text" class='qww' placeholder="1000" style="float: right;">
               </form>
           </div>
           <div class="image">
          <a href="www.google.com"><img src="images.jpg" alt="" style="margin-left: 50px; width: 40px;object-position:right; height: 45px;"> 
          </a>  
        </div>
           <div class="text" >
            <div class="QWERTY" style="font-size: 10px; text-align: right; color: blue;">
                VENTA</div>
            <form  action="index.html" class="Myform" style="font-size:  10px;">PEN
                <label for="" style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold;">&nbsp;S/</label>
                <input type="text" id='long' placeholder="3400" style="float: right;" disabled>
            </form>
            <button class="button" value="compare"><a href="form.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></button>
        </div>
       
           
            
        </div>   
        <div class="initial" style="float: left; font-size: 10px; text-align: center;"  >
            </div>
            <div class="initial" style="float: right;font-size: 10px; text-align: center;">
            VENTA</div>
        <div  id="compare4"style="font-size: 30px;font-weight: bolder; text-align: right;color: blue;">
            
        </div>
        <div id="compare5"style="font-size:12px; text-align: center;color: black;">
            <h4> S/ 54.70</h4>

        </div>
        
    </div>
    <script>
        // we used jQuery 'keyup' to trigger the computation as the user type
        $('.qww').keyup(function () {
         
            // initialize the sum (total price) to zero
            var sum = 0;
             
            // we use jQuery each() to loop through all the textbox with 'price' class
            // and compute the sum for each loop
            $('.qww').each(function() {
                sum =10* Number($(this).val());
            });
             
            // set the computed value to 'totalPrice' textbox
            $('#long').val(sum);
             
        });
        $('.panel').hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('highLight');
});
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```